# Cancel Carbonite Pro account

Tags: account-management

Does anyone know how one would go about canceling a Carbonite Pro Account?

Do I have to call? Or is there a web-interface way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I went about this is I [started a chat](http://carbonite.custhelp.com/app/ask/partner/carbonite_pro) with Carbonite (non pro support).

They then switched me to a Carbonite Pro agent.

The information I needed to cancel my account was:

1. Name of company holding the account
2. Last four (4) digits of card used to pay for account
3. Name on card
4. Billing Address
5. Written (in the chat) confirmation that your backed up data **will** be deleted

And then I had to wait about 10 minutes for the account to be deleted.